# How do I add the output of the last layer of the model to the additional array I created?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have an array called "my_array"

Then I want to add my array "my_array" to the output of the last layer of the model

What should I do? Can this be achieved?

Thanks!

---

if the last layer output called "logits" -> logits = tf.keras.layers.Dense(5)

and then it is regarded as the final output called "output" -> output = logits + my_array

then take this output to train.

```
model = Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activition='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activition='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(5),
])
```

---

Comment: Use the `lambda` layer as the last layer in your sequential model. But make sure that `my_array` is a tensor.

Answer (score 1):

Modify the output of the layer using Lambda layer as mentioned by @Kishore.

Use the below sample code

```
import tensorflow as tf
my_array = ----
model = Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activition='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activition='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(5),
  tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x + my_array)
])
```